# Is it possible to insert tags using insertAdjacentHTML() in order to wrap a certain element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a label and span tag to radio button so as to style it. I want the input and span tags to be wrapped inside the label tag.

Note: I am making design changes to an existing template. The application uses XSLT to flush out the build in the installed template. I have tried to add a label and span tag in the XSLT structure, but resulted in crashing the final build. Only thing that let me add these tags was to insert them during run time.

```
function radio_button() {
var iframe = document.getElementById('questionFrame');
var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;

var inputs = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
if (inputs[i].type=='radio' ) { 
var radio=inputs[i];
radio.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<label>');
radio.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<span></span></label>');
   }
  } 
}
```

My expected result is to make it like this,

```
<label><input type="Radio" name="answer" value="x9" /><span><span></label>
```

but i am getting this instead,

```
<label></label><input type="Radio" name="answer" value="x9" /><span><span>
```

Is there any way to wrap the input tag inside the label tag? Thanks a lot. Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `cloneNode()` to create the desired snippet and then use `replaceChild` with newly created elemnt(s)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
    .forEach(function(radio){
        let label = document.createElement('label');
        let span = document.createElement('span');
          label.appendChild(radio.cloneNode());
          label.appendChild(span);
          radio.parentNode.replaceChild(label, radio);
    });
    

let labels = document.querySelectorAll('label');
console.log(labels[0].innerHTML, labels);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="r8">
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="r8">
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="r8">
    <input type="radio" value="4" name="r8">
  </body>
</html>
```